# issue where an unexpected margin bottom is appearing inside the Paper component of MUI v5

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm experiencing an odd behavior issue where a margin bottom is appearing under the StyledCircularProgress component for no apparent reason. what could be causing this ? I have attached an image depicting the issue as well, I did try to go with position relative on the paper and absolute for the StyledCircularProgress but messed things even more.

```js
// Paper styled component
const StyledPaper = styled(Paper)(({ theme }) => ({
  padding: 0,
  margin: 0,
  backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  borderRadius: '50px',
}));

// Circular Progress Styled component
const StyledCircularProgress = styled(CircularProgress)(({ theme }) => ({
  padding: 0,
  margin: 0,
  backgroundColor: 'red',
  borderRadius: 'inherit',
  width: '16vw',
  maxWidth: '85px',
  // Styles applied to the `svg` element that wraps the circle.
  '& .MuiCircularProgress-circle': {
    strokeLinecap: 'round', // butt, round or square
    strokeWidth: 2.5, // defines the thickness of the circle.
    color: 'green',
  },
}));


return (
      <StyledPaper elevation={3}>
        <StyledCircularProgress />
      </StyledPaper>
    );
```

[image]